# Can VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo::pQueuePriorities be null?

Tags: vulkan

From the official Vulkan Programming Guide:

> The pQueuePriorities field is an optional pointer to an array of
> floating point values representing the relative priority of work
> submitted to each of the queues. These numbers are normalized numbers
> in the range of 0.0 to 1.0. Queues with higher priority may be
> allocated more processing resources or scheduled more aggressively
> than queues with lower priority. Setting pQueuePriorities to nullptr
> has the effect of leaving the queues at the same, default priority

However, when I enable the `VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation` layer I get the following error:

> VUID-VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo-pQueuePriorities-parameter(ERROR / SPEC):
> msgNum: -690544442 - Validation Error: [
> VUID-VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo-pQueuePriorities-parameter ] Object 0:
> VK_NULL_HANDLE, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0xd6d720c6
> | vkCreateDevice: required parameter
> pCreateInfo->pQueueCreateInfos[0].pQueuePriorities specified as NULL.
> The Vulkan spec states: pQueuePriorities must be a valid pointer to an
> array of queueCount float values
> (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.176.1/linux/1.2-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo-pQueuePriorities-parameter)

Should I consider that error as a warning? Or is the book just wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nice thing about the modern Vulkan validation layers is that they directly cite the validation rules they relate to. And their citations are searchable, as each validation rule has a *unique* name. So if you search for "VUID-VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo-pQueuePriorities-parameter" in the Vulkan specification, [you'll find exactly one match](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-khr-extensions/html/chap5.html#VUID-VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo-pQueuePriorities-parameter):

> `pQueuePriorities` **must** be a valid pointer to an array of `queueCount` float values

And of course, the one below that says:

> `queueCount` **must** be greater than 0

So this is an error in the book. And I even checked the old Vulkan 1.0.10 specification (the oldest one I have) to make sure that yes, this parameter was *always* required to be provided. Maybe it was optional in pre-publication days, but I don't know of a released version where it was optional.